# Pull Content From One Page Into Another (Same Domain)

Tags: jquery, html, css, xml, solr

I am trying to pull content from one page into another on the same domain.

I have a ecommerce site with many product listings pages. I am creating a brand page for each brand. At the bottom of that page I would like to show all products available for that brand that are in stock. The easiest and most maintainable way would be to show the ul from the listings page for that brand as then if a product goes out of stock its not shown on the listings page so my theory is it wont show on my new page.

So the question is how do I get page b to show only page a's ul content?

(The  has a class, so is actually ul class=list-products)

Or alternatively is there some HTML that will allow me to display products from a predefined search term?

If its any help the CMS is .net and the search is SOLR

We also have a xml feed for google if there is any way I can use that!

Comment: This really sounds like something that should be solved with a template in the CMS by itself, and not through some hack that require a separate request to a page, extract some content and then massage that content into something usable.

Comment: Yes it would be, however on a .net based custom CMS which I am not allowed access to. The developers are cool about it just to busy to help us do it until next year. They have given me a fair amount of editing ability (Custom CSS/JS per page and standard WISYWIG so looking to see if there is a doable solution with what we have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery's `.load()` function to the rescue:

```
    $( "#elementFromNewPage" ).load( "oldPage.html #elementFromOldPage" );
```

This will effectively grab oldPage.html, perform an innerHTML on `#elementFromOldPage` and place it *within* `#elementFromNewPage`.

For more documentation, see: http://api.jquery.com/load/